# Git Clone --Mirror Option copies everything but not Hooks, Releases, Issues and Insights?

Tags: git, github, migration, github-actions

I have been using below commands to migrate repos from one Server to another Server .
These set of commands copies Code, Branches, Tags, History, Commmits.
But it fails to copy Pull-Requests , Releases (in tags) , Hooks, Issues, Insights.

**git clone --mirror  git@server.A.com:org/repoA.git**

**git remote set-url --push origin git@server.B:org/repoB.git**

**git push --mirror**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImMIF.png)

Is there a way to copy these (Pull-Requests, Releases, Hooks, Issues, Insights ? **Screenshots attached** when a repo is migrated from Server-A to Server-B

Answer (score 2):

Pull Requests are not part of Git,<sup>1</sup> so no, they cannot be copied this way.<sup>2</sup>

Hooks are not part of a repository,<sup>3</sup> so no, they cannot be copied this way.

Tags *are* part of a repository and are already copied this way.  Whether and how you can get GitHub to create "releases" from existing tags is up to GitHub.  [These instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-releases-in-a-repository#creating-a-release) allow you to do it manually; perhaps [the `gh` tool](https://github.com/cli/cli) allows a more automated method.  [The documentation](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release) doesn't say much at first glance but you might find more if you look more closely.

Issues and insights, like the pull requests, are implemented in a GitHub-side database that is not copied by a mirror clone.

It's likely that using `gh` (and/or extending it to use the GitHub API) will let you get closer to your goal.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git has a `request-pull` command, but it sends email.  The kind of pull request you're thinking of is part of a database kept on GitHub, outside of Git.

<sup>2</sup>The *commits* that are part of a pull request can be copied, but the references that implement them are not writable from your end, and even if they were, the database containing the pull request information would be missing.

<sup>3</sup>More precisely, the hooks that live in the `.git/hooks/` directory are deliberately not copied.  If those hooks are symbolic links to scripts that *are* in the repository, you merely need to create those same symlinks in the target repository after `git push --mirror`.  But these hooks are not accessible through GitHub; instead, see the `gh` program and the GitHub API.  It doesn't look like there are ways to fiddle with these from `gh` yet.